# log4net: send email which includes hyperlink

Tags: c#, web-config, log4net, smtpappender

I am using  log4net smtpAppender for sending email to my-system users.

I need the email-body to include hyperlink to my site.
So, I attached the hyperlink to the message string.

However, it seems that something is not right, because since I add it- the email is not sent.

How can I add the hyper Link correctly?

Here is what I tried to do:

```
ILog emailLog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("EmailLogger"); 
string myMsg = "testMsg" + Environment.NewLine + "http://mySiteURL";
emailLog.Error(emailData.Msg);
```

Here is my log4net configuration:

```
<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
  <to  type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{ToAddress}" />
  <from value="myUser@myComp.com" />
  <subject type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{Subject}" />
  <smtpHost value="myHost.net" />
  <username value="muUserName" />
  <password value="myPassword123" />
  <authentication value="Basic" />
  <bufferSize value="512" />
  <lossy value="true" />
  <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
    <threshold value="ERROR" />
  </evaluator>
  <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
    <threshold value="WARN" />
  </evaluator>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%newline%message" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Seems like log4net SmtpAppender is [not supporting Html Emails. you have to create your own Appender.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822709/log4net-html-formatted-smtpappender)

Comment: but it is not html, it is simple message which include only string? –

Comment: There's no reason that log4net would not send this. Perhaps it was rejected by your email server?

Comment: Thanks for your replay. How can I check it?