# log4net SmtpAppender - Change message color

Tags: log4net

Is there a way to change to color of the message to Red?

```
<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
  <threshold value="INFO"/>
  <to value="to@mail.com" />
  <from value="from@mail.com" />
  <subject value="Error in Production" />
  <smtpHost value="localhost" />
  <bufferSize value="512" />
  <lossy value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%newline%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>     
</appender>
```

I would like the mail sent will be in show in red since it simulate production issue.
The console has this error option

```
<mapping>
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <foreColor value="Red, HighIntensity" />
  </mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard smtp appender does not support this. Here is a example of a custom implementation for the smtpappeder which supports html formating:

[Log4net html formatted SmtpAppender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822709/log4net-html-formatted-smtpappender)